# Retreiving multicast with python

Tags: python, sockets, multicast

I am working on a test tool for an existing piece of SW that outputs messages on multicast ip of 240.240.240.1 port 2349. The IP interface on which I am receiving the multicast messages is 192.168.0.4. I can observe these messages being pushed out onto the network via wireshark. Even netstat -ng shows the subscriptions. However, the receiver I wrote in python is not picking them up. I did borrow the code below from another thread, with the attempt to modify it to work in my situation.

```
import socket
import struct
import sys

multicast_group = '240.240.240.1'
server_address = (multicast_group, 2345)

# Create the socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind to the server address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Tell the operating system to add the socket to
# the multicast group on all interfaces.
group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group)
src = bytearray(socket.inet_aton("192.168.0.4"))
mreq = bytearray(group)
mreq.extend(src)
sock.setsockopt(
    socket.IPPROTO_IP,
    socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
    mreq)

# Receive/respond loop
while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    print('received {} bytes from {}'.format(
        len(data), address))
    print(data)

    print('sending acknowledgement to', address)
    sock.sendto(b'ack', address)
```

Any help would be appreciated in figuring out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my own problem.  I had checked iptables as being an issue early on, with no luck. But I fixed/modified several things along the way to address the issues being seen.  Turns out the code above works just fine, it was firewalld/iptables rules blocking the receipt of multicast.